# How to setting GridSplitter's affection to a grid

Tags: c#, uwp, gridsplitter

I use microsoft tool kit in UWP and have something like this

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>                    
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
</Grid>
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
<controls:GridSplitter ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
</Grid>
```

How can i set spliter's affection to column 1 only guys? i dont want column 0 to  be resized like column 1. Like in the image,when i use splitter, i only want splitter resize column 1 only, column 0 is just freeze.

[image: splitter like this]

new code:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>                   
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Red"></Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <controls:GridSplitter GripperCursor="Help" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" ResizeDirection="Columns"
                                       ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext" CursorBehavior="ChangeOnSplitterHover" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ></controls:GridSplitter>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <TextBlock Text="aoisdjaisodjaiosdjsa" Width="60" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one `Grid` so I don't know what grid you want your `GridSplitter` but all you have to do is create a `GridSplitter` with property `Grid.Column` you want to put the control into.

Example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
    <!-- Means GridSplitter stay on column 1 based on the grid he is -->
    <controls:GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
       <!-- Your XAML code here-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

You can use `Grid.RowSpan` if you have to span over all the rows.

Comment: Sorry i think you got me wrong, i've just edit the post for easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

> Like in the image,when i use splitter, i only want splitter resize column 1 only, column 0 is just freeze.

`GridSplitter` has [`ResizeBehavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.gridsplitter.gridresizebehavior?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) property. For your requirement, you could set `ResizeBehavior` as `CurrentAndNext` and `Grid.Column="1"`, then the column will be freezed. you could refer the following.

```
<controls:GridSplitter
        GripperCursor="Help"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Grid.Column="1"
        ResizeDirection="Columns"
        ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext"
        CursorBehavior="ChangeOnSplitterHover"
        Width="10">
  <controls:GridSplitter.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform X="-5" />
  </controls:GridSplitter.RenderTransform>

</controls:GridSplitter>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur time,i did it in my code, but when i hover it, it is a horizontal splitter not vertical splitter. The splitter is at row 1 ,when i use the splitter i want the number 2 row to move up and resize the column 1 not the column 0

Comment: really sorry that my work doesn't allow me to share complete xaml code :(

Comment: you could modify GridSplitter position with Grid.Column  or Grid.Row attach property.

Comment: You need post your code in your case, please avoid to modify the answer with the new post.

Comment: I will check, please wait a moment.

Comment: For your screenshot, do you want to make section 0 freeze when drag red splitter. right ?

Comment: yeah, that's right, column 1 resize and column 0 freeze

Comment: I think you could not  do it, because the red splitter has 2 column span, and  the constraint of  section 0 could not independent existence.

Comment: No it's not,content do distorted

Comment: I tested with community tool kit sample, I have not test with image, could you show the screen shot?